# Keeping a CCLayer on top when using CCGrid3D

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I've been playing around with Cocos2d for a couple of days and got a little bit confused regarding depths (z and vertexz props).

My test app is using CCActionPageTurn3D to create a page-flip action on a CCLayer and everything works fine. But when I try to keep a couple of GUI buttons (A CCLayer with a CCMenu in it) on top of everything they end up *behind* the CCLayer where the action is performed. It doesn't matter that z-value i set the GUI to, but if I sets its vertexZ to a higher value it stays on top (but gets scaled which I don't want it too). Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself by overriding the visit method in my GUI class using glDepthFunc:

```
-(void) visit {

    glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS);
    [super visit];
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

}
```